# Linux, communication between applications

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, process, communication

In my embedded system running Linux (Ubuntu armhf) I have to communicate between processes.
I'm doing it with TCP sockets. It works great but due the high frequency of my requests I have a very high processor usage (94% average measured whit nmon). 
There is a way to lower it using that kind of communication in a more efficient manner?

Comment: Shared memory is the fastest, but you're required to do a lot more management.

Answer (score 3):

`shared memory` and `message queues` can be used to exchange information between processes. The difference is in how they are used. both have some advantage and disadvantage.

**Shared memory**

it's an area of storage that can be read and written by more than one process. It provides no inherent synchronization; in other words, it's up to the programmer to ensure that one process doesn't clobber another's data. But it's efficient in terms of throughput: reading and writing are relatively fast operations.

**A message queue is a one-way pipe:**

one process writes to the queue, and another reads the data in the order it was written until an end-of-data condition occurs. When the queue is created, the message size (bytes per message, usually fairly small) and queue length (maximum number of pending messages) are set. Access is slower than shared memory because each read/write operation is typically a single message. But the queue guarantees that each operation will either processes an entire message successfully or fail without altering the queue. So the writer can never fail after writing only a partial message, and the reader will either retrieve a complete message or nothing at all.

Comment: but what about CPU usage?

Comment: In terms of CPU, MQs are doing everything you have to do with shared memory anyway but the kernel is doing it for you.  The very slight performance hit comes from the syscalls to write/read the queue and the data copying involved.  For all but the very highest performance requirements - which unfortunately many people *think* they have but really don't - you probably won't notice a difference.  If you do, switch to shared memory.  The other limiting factor is the size of the queues.  If you processing gobs and gobs of data then MQs might present a limitation.

Comment: @JKB, a bit of a nit.  The MQ description fits this use case but MQs are not necessarily one-way and not necessarily strictly FIFO as they can be manipulated using priorities and/or message types.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to stick with your basic architecture, you can switch from TCP sockets to Unix domain sockets (AF_UNIX/AF_LOCAL).  Since it's a strictly local protocol, it doesn't have the overhead of TCP.